# How to connect a Facebook account to Adium?

Tags: facebook, chat, adium

For some reason I can't get Adium to connect to Facebook. Facebook refuses to log me in every time I try.

I have the right email address and the right password... but it keeps asking for password.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Facebook updated its chat system, breaking Adium's support. You can still connect to Facebook but you need to setup the account as a **Jabber account**.

Your username will be `Your_Facebook_Username@chat.facebook.com`. The server is `chat.facebook.com`. The port is `5222` and you should not use SSL.

Comment: It's also worth linking to the official Facebook Chat page: http://www.facebook.com/sitetour/chat.php

Comment: SSL is working fine for me. i've enabled "Require ssl" but not "old style ssl".

Answer (score 0):

On April 30th 2015, Facebook disabled Jabber support. There is currently no way to connect to Facebook's chat service from Adium. The developers are [aware of the issue](https://trac.adium.im/ticket/16921), and work is being done in Pidgin (whose protocol library Adium piggy-backs on) to make Facebook chat functional again.